# Piping docker run container ID to docker exec

Tags: bash, docker, pipe, exec

In my development, I find myself issuing a `docker run` command followed by a `docker exec` command on the resulting container ID quite frequently. It's a little annoying to have to copy/paste the container ID between commands, so I was trying to pipe the container ID into my `docker exec` command.

Here's my example command.

`docker run -itd image | xargs -i docker exec -it {} bash`

This starts the container, but then I get the following error.

```
the input device is not a TTY
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get around this?

Edit: I also forgot to mention I have an ENTRYPOINT defined and cannot override that.

Comment: -it **and** d?.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Best of both worlds!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
ID=$(docker run -itd image)  && docker exec -it $ID bash
```

Because `xargs` executes it arguments without allocating a new tty.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to "bash"-into the container you do not have to pass the container-id around. You can simply run

```
docker run -it --rm <image> /bin/bash
```

For example, if we take the ubuntu base image

```
docker run -it --rm ubuntu /bin/bash
root@f80f83eec0d4:/#
```

from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

> -t              : Allocate a pseudo-tty
>   -i              : Keep STDIN open even if not attached
>   --rm : Automatically remove the container when it exits

The command /bin/bash [overwrites](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cmd-default-command-or-options) the default command that is specified with the CMD instruction in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention I already have an ENTRYPOINT defined that cannot be overwritten.